# Creating a new class with similar functions as an ArrayList, errors in adding values?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, nullpointerexception

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sequence {

    private ArrayList<Integer> values;

    public void Sequence(){ 
        values = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    }

    public void addValue(int ad){
        this.values = values;
        values.add(ad);          
    }

    public String toString(){
        return values.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sequence a = new Sequence();
        a.addValue(1);
        a.addValue(2);
        System.out.println(a.toString());
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why I'm getting an `NullPointerException` for the code above.

I'm trying to create a class `Sequence` that is similar to an `ArrayList`, and gives it new methods. When adding the new values to the `ArrayList`, I get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` because you have defined a method `void Sequence()` instead of a constructor `Sequence()`. Therefore, the constructor that you're calling on the first line in the main method is the *default constructor*.

The default constructor's behaviour is to call the super class's no-argument constructor (in this case `Object()`) and in this case will leave the sequence without anything assigned.

Constructors do not specify a return type (like `void` which specifies that there is no return type). In this case, it would be defined as follows:

```
public Sequence() { 
    values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```